# Check for empty space and return a boolean

Tags: list, f#, boolean

I have made a list that has some values in it, i am trying to find the   average value of the list. Is there a smarter way to do this and  How do i check for empty space/list like so [ . ] and return boolean "false"?

```
let gennemsnit = List.average [0.0; 0.1; 0.3; 0.4; 1.0; 1.1; 1.1; 1.2; 1.5; 2.0]
     if Array.contains then 
         printfn "false"
     else 
         printfn "%f" gennemsnit
```

Comment: What is the definition of an "empty space" in your data? Does a value of 0.0 mean an empty space? It can't be a `null` value, because floating-point numbers in F# are not allowed to be null. Once we know what you mean by an "empty space", we'll be able to answer your question.

Comment: if there is a empty space  as this [ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute the average of a list of floats but return an indication that there is no average in case the list of values is empty. Is that correct? If so, you cannot return an average value or a boolean… but you can return an optional value:

```
let average = function
    | [] -> None
    | values -> Some (List.average values)

average [0.0; 0.1; 0.3; 0.4; 1.0; 1.1; 1.1; 1.2; 1.5; 2.0]
|> printfn "%A"

average []
|> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

```
"F# Compiler for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)

Some 0.87
<null>
```

**EDIT:** The output `<null>` is due to a compiler optimization that represents `None` as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using an `Option` type as suggested by dumetrulo, you can use the `Result` type to describe your business errors in a domain-specific way.  For instance, you could define a type that enumerates your expected error-cases, including the list being empty or any other rules you may have (let's say you don't want to allow any negative values in the list), and then return `Error` with the specific failure case or `Ok` with the value:

```
type AggregateError =
| ListIsEmpty
| ListContainsNegativeValues

let average = function
| [] -> Error ListIsEmpty
| list when list |> List.exists ((>) 0.0) -> Error ListContainsNegativeValues
| values -> Ok <| List.average values
```

Here, if you run `average` for an empty list, you get `Error ListIsEmpty`.

```
average [];;

val it : Result<float,AggregateError> = Error ListIsEmpty
```

If you run `average` for a list that contains one or more negative values, you get `Error ListContainsNegativeValues`.

```
average [1.0; -1.0];;

val it : Result<float,AggregateError> = Error ListContainsNegativeValues
```

Otherwise, you get `Ok` with the actual average value:

```
average [0.0; 1.0; 3.0; 5.0];;

val it : Result<float,AggregateError> = Ok 2.25
```